# Trying to read values returned on jsp form submission in springboot project by setters and use the combination to call another java class

Tags: forms, spring-boot, jsp, setter, getter

So, I have values in getter setter variables when I click on form submit but now want to have those values in variables and check combination of them to run code from another java class

I have tried using parametrized constructor or may be having a common setter but that did not help.

```
package com.grt.dto;

import java.util.Set;

public class WDPayrollRecon {

    public Set<String> dataType;
    public String planCountry;
    public String payPeriod;
    public String currentPeriod;
    public String lastPayPeriod;
    Set<String> test;

    public Set<String> getdataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setdataType(Set<String> dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
        System.out.println("this is dataType" +dataType);
        test = dataType;
    }
    public String getPlanCountry() {
        return planCountry;
    }
    public void setPlanCountry(String planCountry) {
        this.planCountry = planCountry;
    }
    public String getPayPeriod() {
        return payPeriod;
    }
    public void setPayPeriod(String payPeriod) {
        this.payPeriod = payPeriod;
    }
    public String getCurrentPeriod() {
        return currentPeriod;
    }
    public void setCurrentPeriod(String currentPeriod) {
        this.currentPeriod = currentPeriod;
    }
    public String getlastPayPeriod() {
        return lastPayPeriod;
    }
    public void setlastPayPeriod(String lastPayPeriod) {
        this.lastPayPeriod = lastPayPeriod;
    }
    public WDPayrollRecon()
    {

    }
    public WDPayrollRecon(Set<String> dataType,String planCountry,String payPeriod,String currentPeriod,String lastPayPeriod)
    {
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.planCountry = planCountry;
        this.payPeriod = payPeriod;
        this.currentPeriod = currentPeriod;
        this.lastPayPeriod = lastPayPeriod;
        if(dataType.contains("GTLI")& planCountry.equals("USA")){
            System.out.println("This is test");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("This is not test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question.Try to elaborate it more with specific problem you are facing , excepted output etc.

Comment: @Swati   1. So, I am designing very simple and basic springboot app which takes input from user in a form (like what country and payperiod etc) , the values user chose I get that using getter and setters. 2. Now, based on what user has selected ( not supposed to show any output ) as results would be mailed , I am supposed to call another java class which holds logic on what to do for each combination.3. Problem is I don't know how to call that logic class in getter setter class for it to perform actions

Comment: Okay , try to post more code , i.e how you call your `getter-setter` .

Comment: @Swati1. WDPayrollRecoWebApplication with@SpringBootApplication to run  2.Controller class -- "@RequestMapping(value= "/reconciliation")
 public ModelAndView reconciliationForm(Model model) {
  return new ModelAndView("WDPayrollRecon-page", "WDPayrollRecon", new WDPayrollRecon());
 }
 @RequestMapping(value="/submitForm")
 public String reconsubmitForm(@ModelAttribute("WDPayrollRecon") WDPayrollRecon recon) {
  return "confirmation-page";
 }" 3.The class that has get-set "WDPayrollRecon" is posted above  4. There is a class WDProcessAutomationUtils which has all the logic to perform

Comment: Also, WDPayrollRecon-page and confirmation-page are jsp pages snippet <form:form action="submitForm" modelAttribute="WDPayrollRecon">
   <form:select path="planCountry" color="Navy">
    <form:option value="India" style="color: Navy" label="India" />
    <form:option value="USA" style="color: Navy" label="USA" />
   </form:select>   2.  confirmation-page ---<font size="4" color="Navy "> Plan Country : ${WDPayrollRecon.planCountry} </font> <br>

Comment: You can `get` values set in `setter method` by using i.e: `String period=recon.getlastPayPeriod();` get all values in this way and pass this in your class `WDProcessAutomationUtils ` to do further processing .

Comment: @Swati - How to call WDProcessAutomationUtils in the controller class, if I want the process in the class mentioned above to do processing after submit button is clicked and /submitform is called of jsp processing.